# MainActivity must be declared abstract or implement interface X

Tags: java, android

I have the interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public void myTask (ServiceHandler.SongInfo[] songInfo);
}
```

I have the ServiceHandler.SongInfo class

```
public class SongInfo {
        public String wrapperType;
        public String kind;
        public Integer artistId;
        public Integer collectionId
        //etc
    }
```

I have the decleration

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {

    //... Everything else 

    @Override 
    void myTask(SongInfo[] songInfo){

    }

 }
```

But I sill get the error unless I comment out this line in my interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

    //public void myTask (ServiceHandler.SongInfo[] songInfo);
}
```

What does it mean?

Comment: Where's the `myTask()` method in the Activity? To implement an interface, it has to have all of the methods declared in the interface.

Comment: The overriden method is at the bottom of my main activity.

Comment: Then I would guess that you're not overriding it correctly. Make sure the signature and return type are exactly as specified in the interface.

Comment: You have an uppercase `M` on the method name in the Activity. Should be `public void myTask (SongInfo[] songInfo)`. Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: The capitalization correction didn't change anything. Like I said, if I comment out `//public void myTask (ServiceHandler.SongInfo[] songInfo);` then the error goes away, so maybe the error doesn't have anything to do with the implementation.

Comment: Okay, you were right. It was the implementation.

Comment: You're saying it's not okay not to have a modifier?

Comment: Do you have two `SongInfo` classes? I would've thought your IDE would've complained about that first, if not. And, in general, you always want to specify a scope modifier.

Comment: No, I only have one SongInfo class, but that's a good point. Should have caught it earlier anyways. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change `songInfo[]` to `ServiceHandler.SongInfo[]` in the implementation argument